# How to run two methods in parallel in Groovy?

Tags: groovy, parallel-processing, parallel.foreach, groovyshell

**[Example](https://tio.run/##Sy/Kzy@r/P8/JTVNIbcyJ7O4RMFWIVo9syQ111BdB0wbqcdycUHk9FITkzMUqhWAgAtEKKSV5hlqaMLZRkB2LRcXyDCIjEI1WK6gKDOvJCdPQQkomlySmZ@na6iEpNAIj0IjoML//wE) :**

```
def mylist = ['item1','item2']
mylist.each {    
     fun1()
     fun2()
}

def fun1() {
    println "function-1"
}

def fun2() {
    println "function-2"
}
```

**Actual result :**

```
function-1
function-2
function-1
function-2
```

**Expected result :**
same as above, however **I want `fun1()` and `fun2()` to be called in parallel for each item** in the list. It does not matter the sequence of output as in my actual code, both methods are independent of each other.

Comment: Thread.start{ ... }

Comment: http://www.gpars.org/guide/

Answer (score 2):

As cfrick says, you can use GPars which is now part of groovy:

```
import static groovyx.gpars.GParsPool.*

def mylist = ['item1','item2']

withPool {
    mylist.eachParallel {    
       fun1()
       fun2()
    }
}

def fun1() {
    println "function-1"
}

def fun2() {
    println "function-2"
}
```